# Synchronizing messages without time headers

Tags: python, custom-message, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to synchronize subscription from a few topics from custom messages.

> armj_cmd_pos_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/arm_controller/position_command", JointPositions)
> armj_cmd_vel_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/arm_controller/velocity_command", JointVelocities)
> armj_cmd_eff_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/arm_controller/effort_command", JointTorques)
> armj_states_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/joint_states", JointState)

It gave me

> AttributeError: 'JointPositions'
> object has no attribute 'header'

I am suspecting the /arm_controller/position_command topic.

The type of the /arm_controller/position_command topic is brics_actuator/JointPositions
and the content is

> Poison poisonStamp
> JointValue[] positions

and the content of JointValue is

> time timeStamp          #time of the data

> string joint_uri

> string unit             #if empy expects si units, you can use boost::unit

> float64 value

my question is how do I get rid of the attribute error? How to synchronize topics when their message don't have headers? Is there a way to add headers without meddling with the message files?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60568/synchronizing-messages-without-time-headers/) by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without extra work, you can't. Simply because the filter needs to know what to synchronize.

The main problem here is that the message you pointed out doesn't use a Header, but a custom stamp. At least there is one, so probably the easiest method is to use the filters manually.
I haven't checked the API, but I'd try to not directly use the subscriber as an input, but instead put your own "FixHeaderForMyCustomMsg"-Filter in between that just constructs a data type that contains your message + a header (that you fill from the stamp). Given pythons typing, you should be able to just pass that into the TimeSynchronizer.

Meddling with built-in messages probably won't work as the types are defined using **slots** (probably for efficiency), so you can't change that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on 2013-04-14**:
Does that mean the following steps: (1) Subscribe to the topic and get the message (2) republish the message with another topic with a message with header (3) And subscribe to the new topic ? Or is there a better way?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-14**:
No. There is no need to republish. Basically message_filters are filters, so just take the message and put it in something that has a header. That something you should be able to put into the message filter.